# In a PDE solution let us integrate out one of two coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

Here is a trapezoid within which I am solving a simple Laplace equation with the Dirichlet boundary conditions set at its top and bottom:

```
    Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
coord = {{0, 0}, {1/3, 1}, {2/3, 1}, {1, 0}};
incidents = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}};
bm = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coord2, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bm];
mesh["Wireframe"]
sigma = 1;
nds = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Div][
     sigma*Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 1]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh]
```

[image]

Now I would like to calculate the integral of the square of the result gradient: `Evaluate[Grad[nds, {x, y}].Grad[nds, {x, y}]]` over x lying within the mesh, and study the dependence of the result on y.

How can I do that?

The result should probably be a nested list of with the sublists structure `{yi, resi}`, where `yi`is the point coordinate along `y`, and `resi` is the integral value in this point.

What I do understand myself, is that I could divide the initial trapezoid into several parts, and then integrate within each such a part and, thus, make a list. I am curious, if there is a more regular approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two minor changes to the code

```
bm = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coord, 
     "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents]}];
nds = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Div][sigma*Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
        DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0], 
        DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 1]}, u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
```

the first to correct a typo, and the second for convenience, we obtain

```
Plot3D[nds[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh]
```

[image]

and

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Grad[nds[x, y], {x, y}].Grad[nds[x, y], {x, y}]], {x, y} ∈ 
    mesh, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

To obtain the integral described in the question, define

```
f[y0_] := Quiet@NIntegrate[Evaluate[Grad[nds[x, y], {x, y}].Grad[nds[x, y], {x, y}]] 
    /. y -> y0, {x, y0/3, 1 - y0/3}]
```

which gives, for instance,

```
f[.7]
(* 0.672611 *)
```

Comment: I see the typo you corrected (coord instead of coord2), but cannot find, what was the second correction. Please kindly let me know.

Comment: I changed `u[x. y], {x, y} ∈ mesh` to `u, {x, y} ∈ mesh` at the end of `NDSolveValue`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your above answer very much.